# Convert files following the order of a list C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, converters

I need to convert images(like `.jpg`) to PDF files for an assignment for school. I have a `ListBox` where I put the pages of the PDF file, so the user can reorder the list and convert the files in that order. 
I have the files in a temporary folder in order to get the files there to convert them to PDF.

**My problem here is :** how do I convert the files with the order that the user had chosen?

I already searched and I tried to do a Class with the strings `ID` and `Name` so i get the ID from the item in the ListBox and change it on a new list. And i think after, I do a foreach() loop where I get the files from the temporary folder and merge them in a new PDF file, but to do in the order I want, I think I have to compare the name of the file with the name in the list and, if it matches, convert and add it, if not, pass to the next file.
But I don't know how to do it.

Can please someone help me getting this right? 
Thanks in advance!

I'm sending my code to:

```
   //the open files button
   private void proc2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        OpenFileDialog dialogo = new OpenFileDialog();

        dialogo.Title = "Search files";

        dialogo.InitialDirectory = @"E:\";

        dialogo.Filter = "Images (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.tiff,.tif) |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*tiff;*tif|All of the files (*.*)|*.*";

        DialogResult resposta = dialogo.ShowDialog();
        if (resposta == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string caminhoCompleto = dialogo.FileName;
            caminho2 = dialogo.SafeFileName;
            caminhotb2.Text = caminhoCompleto;
            string fish = "";
            string path = @"C:\temporario";
            if(Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                 fish=Path.Combine(path, caminho2);                   
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                fish = Path.Combine(path, caminho2);
            }
            File.Create(fish);
            listaimg.Items.Add(caminho2);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public string[] GetFilesImg4() //jpg files
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\temporario"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\temporario");
        }
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temporario");
        FileInfo[] fileInfos4 = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
        foreach (FileInfo info in fileInfos4)
        {
            if (info.Name.IndexOf("protected") == -1)
                list4.Add(info.FullName);
        }

        return (string[])list4.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

Comment: Hint : change the name of the file in the temporary folder to include the select order number.  Or create a bunch of temporary folders with the select number.  The best way of doing it would be to create a List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> where the int is the select order and the string is the full path name of selected file.

Comment: Why not just iterate the items in the `ListBox` (which will give you the correct order)?

Comment: why is the order important? do both selection of the files and getting list of the files happen in the same process or in different processes?

Comment: Thank you all. The order is important to me because I want to add things to my project so it is more complete for the users @aiodintsov

Comment: @Zer0 I can't understand your comment, can you be more explicit please?

Comment: @jdweng can you show me an example please? I get what you are saying but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If both actions happen in the same process, you can just store the list of file names in memory (and you already do add them to `listaimg`):

```
public string[] GetFilesImg4() //jpg files
{
    string tempPath = @"C:\temporario";
    if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
    {
        foreach (string filename in listimga.Items)
        {
            if (!filename.Contains("protected"))
                list4.Add(Path.Combine(tempPath, filename);
        }
    }

    return (string[])list4.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

if these are different processes then you can just dump content of your `listimga` at some point and then read it from the same file. In the example below I store it to file named "order.txt" in the same directory, but logic may be more complicated, such as merging several files with a timestamp and such.

```
// somewhere in after selecting all files
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temporario\order.txt", listimga.Items.Select(t=>t.ToString()));


public string[] GetFilesImg4() //jpg files
{
    string tempPath = @"C:\temporario";
    if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
    {
        var orderedFilenames = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(tempPath, "order.txt")); // list of files loaded in order
        foreach (string filename in orderedFilenames)
        {
            if (!filename.Contains("protected"))
                list4.Add(Path.Combine(tempPath, filename);
        }
    }

    return (string[])list4.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

it's also a good idea to examine available method on a class, such as in this case `string.IndexOf(s) == -1` is equivalent to `!string.Contains(s)` and the latter is much more readable at least for an English speaking person.

I also noticed that your users have to select documents one by one, but FileOpen dialogs allow to select multiple files at a time, and I believe it preserves the order of selection as well.

If order of selection is important and file open dialogs don't preserve order or users find it hard to follow you can still use multiple file selection open dialog and then allow to reorder your `listimga` list box to get the order right.

Comment: I'm trying it, if it works I'm marking it as answer, Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe you have an error in `listaimg.Items.Select()` because there is no such "Select()" in List.Items

Comment: @SofiaRodrigues That's LINQ.  Make sure you add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @SofiaRodrigues as Zer0 mentioned, it's LINQ. It's a convenient way to work with collections. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select and other methods there, they are used often.

Comment: So, let me see if I get this right... I should use Linq for my query. 
I have to put the first line of your second code, for example, in the convert button, but befofe I call the Convert function. Then the rest of the code will get every line of that file that will be in that order.... Is that it?